# Deletion and insertion of new records to DB without refreshing

Tags: jquery

i am trying to add and delete records(games) from my database using jquery and ajax.
i am still a junior software engineer and learning the basics of web development but i have this task to accomplish and unsure what i am missing for it to work.

i have 5 columns from my database and the ID is hidden with auto increment.

my question is what is broken in the code that is not letting me add or delete a game and reflect it on the database???

this is my main file with the calls to delete and add games.

```
            <script type = "text/javaScript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-             latest.js""></script>
         <script type = "text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("add games").Submit(function()
          $("#add").load("add.php");  {
         var id = $("#ID").val();
         var name = $("#name").val();
         var type = $("#type").val();
         var rating = $("#score").val();
         var release = $("Yreleased").val();
         var dataString = 'ID=' + id 'name='+ name + '&username=' + type + '&password=' + rating +                           '&gender=' + release;
         if (id =='' || name == '' || type == '' || rating == '' || release == '')
         {
         alert("please enter some valid data for your game entry");
         }
         else
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "add.php",
         data: dataString,
         success: function(){
         $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
         $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
         }
         });
         }
         return false;
         });
         });



         </script>


         <body>
         <?php

         include("dbconfig.php");
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM games";
         $result = mysql_query($sql);
         while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

         echo "</br> Game ID: " .$record['ID']. "</br> Game Name: " .$record['Name']. 
         "<br /> Game Type: ".$record['Type']. "<br /> Rating: ".$record['Rating']."<br /> Year Released: ".$record['Release Year']."<br /> <br />" ?>


     <a href="#" id="<?php echo $record["ID"]; ?>" class="deletebutton"><img src="trash.png" alt="delete"/></a> 






  <?php
         }

         ?>

         <form name="add" id ="add" action="add.php"  method="post">
         <input class ="gameID" type="hidden" id="ID" value = " ' .$record['ID'] . ' " /> 
         <b>Game Name: </b> <input type="text" id="name" size=70> 
         <b>Game Type:</b> <input type="text" id="type" size=40>
         <b>Rating: </b> <input type="number"  id="score" min="1.0" max="10.0"  step ="0.1"/>
         <b>Year Released: </b> <input type="number"  min="1900" max="2011" id="Yreleased" value="1985" size=4>


         <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" id = "Submit" value="Add Game" class = "add games"></p>
         </form>



         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" 
         $(document).ready(function() {

         $("a.deletebutton").click(function(){

         var del_id = element.attr("id");
         var info = 'id=' + del_id;
         var parent = $(this).parent();
         if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this game? !"))
         {
         $.ajax({
         type: "get",
         url: "delete.php",
         data: parent.attr('id').replace('record-',"),
         success: function(){
         }
         });
         $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
         .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
         }
             return false;
             });
             });
             </script>




             </body>
```

and i have  very simple php files for add, for delete and for the dbconfig

for delete.php

```
<?php

// This is a sample code in case you wish to check the username from a mysql db table
include("dbconfig.php");
if(($_GET['id'])
{
$id=$_GET['id'];

 $sql = "DELETE from games where ID='.(int)$_GET['id'];
 $result= mysql_query( $sql);






}

?>
```

and this is my add.php and my dbconfig.php in the end

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])

$name=$_POST['name'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$rating=$_POST['score'];
$release=$_POST['Yreleased'];
$sql = ("INSERT INTO games  VALUES ($name, $type, $rating, $release)");

echo " your game has been added to the list of games. ";
?>
```

and last my dbconfig

```
 <?php
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "gamebook";
$server = "localhost";


$bd = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password) or die ('I cannot connect to the        database because:' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database);
?>
```

this is the first time every i post a question and ask, so if i did something unacceptable or that should have been done otherwise, i would appreciate the tips, help, links, or if someone can help me on how to fix my issue. 
i can read from the database, but not add or delete from it dynamically.

Comment: i am unable to delete a record dynamically without refreshing  and removing from the DB
same for adding a game.
i cant add a game and see it reflected in the database.

all the code is doing right is reading from the database and displaying the records . i see the delete button under each record  but it doesnt work

Comment: Please narrow down your issue to a specific component, and format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete.php

```
<?php
  require('dbconfig.php'); //we cannot continue without this file, thats why using require instead of include
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM `games` WHERE `ID`="'.$id.'" LIMIT 1';
    mysql_query( $sql);
    echo 'deleted';
  }
?>
```

add.php

```
<?php
  require('dbconfig.php'); //we cannot continue without this file, thats why using require instead of include

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    $name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
    $type=addslashes($_POST['type']);
    $rating=addslashes($_POST['score']);
    $release=addslashes($_POST['Yreleased']);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `games` (`Name`,`Type`,`Rating`,`Release Year`)  VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$type.'", "'.$rating.'", "'.$release.'")'; 
    mysql_query( $sql);
    if(!mysql_errno())
      echo " your game has been added to the list of games. ";
    }
?>
```

index.php take from here: http://pastebin.com/NVbheAJZ

Comment: thank you so much. i reread the code you posted and fixed the code i had accordingly.although it did not fix the issue for me they are way more neat 
4 fields u wrote r right in table.
if i try to add a game i get this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\add.php on line 8..
for deletion i press on the button to delete under every record but it does not take me anywhere.. 
if there are tips to debug my code and how to do it... any hints would be appreciated. and thank u for the reply 0leg too.. i will start looking at my index.php now to see where is the issue

Comment: im suggesting you to use http://getfirebug.com/ plugin for your browser (FF or Chrome) Then you can see ajax calls when you press buttons. I hope it helps.

Comment: sorry, my fault. please update add.php from my 1 Answer and it will works.

Comment: first of all thank you very much
1- the delete is working now when i test it but it does not remove the record from the database, i am not sure why but i will continue testing it.

2- i downloaded firebug and will start using it thanks for the tip :)

3- the add is now working and is adding to the database but i want it to work without refreshing too like the delete is doing.

4- do you think i should keep on using notepad++ or should i use some editor with auto complete enabled maybe to ease the completion of the syntax. 
thank u in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086800/jquery-ajax-what-is-wrong-in-my-javascript-function-delete-record-add-recor

check this Oleg, i am able to delete now in that and reflect on the database, but the adding is not working