# jquery + ajax. what is wrong in my javascript function? delete record, add record without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What is wrong with my JavaScript? It is breaking somewhere to add a record without refreshing the page.

i finished deleting completely now with the aid of some experienced users. but now adding a record to the database is not working yet

i want to add a record dynamically now without refreshing.. deleting is functioning well and it is being reflected on the database.

I will include 4 files and my database:

- the files are `index.php` for my main
- `add.php` for adding a record
- `delete.php` for deleting a record
- dbconfig for the database connection and configuration

### `index.php`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
     <title>title</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <?php
include("dbconfig.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM games";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  echo "<p class=\"p" .$record['ID']. "\"></br> Game ID: " .$record['ID']. "</br> Game  Name: " .$record['Name'].
 "<br /> Game Type: ".$record['Type']. "<br /> Rating: ".$record['Rating']."<br /> Year  Released: ".$record['Release Year']."<br /> <br />" ?>
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $record["ID"]; ?>" class="deletebutton"><img src="trash.png" alt="delete"/> </a></p>
<?php
 }
?>

 <form name="add" id ="add" action=""  method="post">
 <input class ="gameID" type="hidden" id="ID" name="ID" value = " ' .$record['ID'] . ' " />
 <b>Game Name: </b> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size=70>
 <b>Game Type:</b> <input type="text" id="type" name="type" size=40>
 <b>Rating: </b> <input type="number"  id="score"  name="score" min="1.0" max="10.0"  step ="0.1"/>
 <b>Year Released: </b> <input type="number"  min="1900" max="2011" id="Yreleased" name="Yreleased" value="1985" size=4>
 <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" id = "Submit" value="Add Game" class = "add games"></p>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#add").submit(function(){


                        var name =    this['name'].value;
                        var type =    this['type'].value;
                        var rating =  this['score'].value;
                        var release = this['Yreleased'].value;
                        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&type=' + type + '&rating=' + rating + '&release=' + release;

                    if (name == '' || type == '' || rating == '' || release == ''){
                        alert("please enter some valid data for your game entry");
                    }else
                    $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "add.php",
                         data: dataString,
                         success: function(){
                           window.location.reload(true);
                          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                          $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                         }
                    });

           return false;
        }

                                )});

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.deletebutton").click(function(){
             var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
             var info = 'id=' + del_id;
             var parent = $(this).parent();
            if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this game? !..There is no Undo")){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "delete.php?" + info,

                    context: document.body,
                    success: function(){

                        $('.p'+del_id).html('deleted');
                        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    }
                });
            }
             return false;
     });
 });
 </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

### `add.php`:

```
<?php
    require('dbconfig.php'); //we cannot continue without this file, thats why using require instead of include

    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {

    $name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
    $type=addslashes(($_POST['type']));
    $rating=addslashes($_POST['rating']);
    $release=addslashes($_POST['release']);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `games` (`Name`,`Type`,`Rating`,`Release Year`)  VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$type.'", "'.$rating.'", "'.$release.'")'; 
    mysql_query( $sql);
    if(!mysql_errno())
    echo " your game has been added to the list of games. ";
    }
?>
```

### `delete.php`:

```
    <?php
    require('dbconfig.php'); //we cannot continue without this file, thats why using require instead of include
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM `games` WHERE `ID`="'.$id.'" LIMIT 1';
        mysql_query( $sql);
        echo 'deleted';
    }
    ?>
```

### dbconfig:

```
    <?php
    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "gamebook";
    $server = "localhost";


    $bd = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password) or die ('I cannot connect to  the database because:' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database);
    ?>
```

If needed, here's the schema for my database as well:

```
    SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";


    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

    --
    -- Database: `gamebook`
    --
    CREATE DATABASE `gamebook` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
    USE `gamebook`;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `games`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` (
    `ID` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `Type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `Rating` float NOT NULL,
    `Release Year` int(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `games`
    --

    INSERT INTO `games` (`ID`, `Name`, `Type`, `Rating`, `Release Year`) VALUES
    (1, 'Battlefield 3', 'First Person Shooter', 8.5, 2011),
    (2, 'Fifa 12', 'Sports', 9.2, 2004),
    (3, 'Red Alert 3', 'Strategy ', 8.8, 2007),
    (4, 'Fight Night Round 4', 'Fighting', 9, 2010),
    (5, '', '', 0, 0),
    (6, '', '', 0, 0);

    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

What is wrong in my javascript and what is the best way to figure out??

Is there a good text editor you guys recommend for beginners like myself?

Comment: ye gods, at least tell us what is not working...Does the request not fire?  Does it not return?  Do you get JS error? what!

Comment: i am sorry
i am new to asking
basically if you remove the comments for the add function in index.php nothing will work, but because i commented out the add function the delete is working by hiding the record, but it is not being removed from the database and when i refresh i see all the records again.. as for add i want to do it dynamically and it is not working at all. but with refreshing it adds them successfully to the database.

Comment: Looks like your not passing in any data to your delete.php, in your delete.php you are checking for  if(isset($_GET['id']))
but in your ajax you are not passing in any data string for that id,

Comment: i am passing it now, and edited the code. still it is not removed from the web or the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice a few things right off the bat.

## jQuery Syntax

First of all, your JavaScript syntax is off.  In your first file (`index.php`) you have the following line:

```
 $("#add").load("add.php") {
```

That's not the proper syntax of the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.  Basically, you have this:

```
$("#add").load("add.php") {
  // ... stuff to happen after add.php loads
}
```

What you *should* have is this:

```
$("#add").load("add.php", function() {
  // .. stuff to happen after add.php loads
});
```

Remember, you need to add this extra functionality in the form of a *callback* otherwise it's not going to work.

## Inconsistent calls

In the first code block I addressed, it looks like you're trying to load `add.php` and then fire some JavaScript commands after you've loaded it.  But looking at the source of your `add.php` file, you don't want to do this.  Your `add.php` file contains the server-side code to process adding a record to the database ... you don't load it directly, you just submit POST requests to it.

## Invalid data

You're not sending your data to the server properly.  With the add routine, you're first creating a data string:

```
var dataString = 'ID=' + id 'name='+ name + '&username=' + type + '&password=' + rating + '&gender=' + release;
```

Then you're sending that in your data package via AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    }
});
```

The problem here is two-fold.  Firstly, you're not encoding the data right.  `'ID=' + id 'name='` is missing a `+` character and will break.  But even with that fixed, you'd be concatenating data improperly.  Your `dataString` variable would end up looking like:

```
ID=1name=Bob&username=my_user&password=password&gender=male
```

You see how you're missing a `&` symbol?  This is an easy mistake to make, so instead send a data *object*.  You're less likely to miss characters:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add.php",
    data: {

    },
    success: function(){
        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    }
});
```

## Data mismatch

Next, you're passing data to the server but checking for different values.  Your JavaScript to add data looks like it wants to send:

- ID
- name
- username
- password
- gender

But your `add.php` is checking for:

- Submit
- name
- type
- score
- Yreleased

## Missing Data

With your delete routine, you're checking for the value of "ID" in a GET.  That means this value needs to be passed as a *query argument* appended to the URL.  For example: `delete.php?ID=5` to delete a game with the ID of 5.

You're checking for this just fine in the PHP, but you're not actually sending the data in your AJAX request.  Your code *should* look more like this:

```
$("a.deletebutton").click(function(){
    var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this game? !")){
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "delete.php?" + info,
            context: document.body,
            success: function(){
                $('.p'+del_id).html('deleted');
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

See `url: "delete.php"` becomes `url: "delete.php?" + info`?  This will append your ID to the url and make `$_GET['id']` available in PHP.

Comment: EAmann, thanks for all the addition and info, i fixed the stuff u mentioned for add.php but i didnot get what is wrong with my datastring i am passing and how to fix it, i added the missing + though,   .. for the delete it is now not removing the record from the webpage nor the database when i press any delete button. in inspect element every delete id reflects the right ID but still nothing is happening. 
should i add to  $.ajax for delete.php 
data :info , it is still not working even when i add it 

i did not touch add function but fixed all issues u mentioned. thanks for ur time too

Comment: If you've changed your code, please change the code snippets in your question.  Otherwise we can't see what you've changed and can't offer any additional help.

Comment: i edited the script for the delete function to pass the id when i click the delete button, still not reflected on database nor on the webpage it is not removed. i kept the add record commented out to simplify things in order to make things work one by one but i still tried to change some things in the code for adding script

Comment: Don't forget the `?` character.  Right now, you're sending your AJAX request to `delete.phpid=X`.  You need to send it to `delete.php?id=X` in order for PHP to see the value you're sending.  Change `url: "delete.php" + info` to `url: "delete.php?" + info`

Comment: thanks EAMann, i fixed it. i get the message now that if you are sure you want to delete a record, but it does not fade away and get removed from neither the web nor the database. thanks for the feedback, appreciated.

Comment: You need to use a tool like Firebug or Fiddler to view the actual AJAX message your system is putting together.  You should be able to see a GET request being made to `delete.php?id=X` and make sure that it's the right URL and the right ID.  If anything goes wrong, you wills ee that, too.  If it doesn't fade, that means jQuery isn't firing your `success` callback ... so something is going wrong.

Comment: thanks EAMann. the delete is now working well and the success function is working very well and hiding the record, and the database is reflecting it too. your tips and help is appreciated. i know u told me there is a mismatch in sending datastring for add script but how can i fix it, i am not sure what is broken in that script

Comment: You need to fix two things - first, `var dataString = 'ID=' + id +'name='+ name + 'type=' + type + 'rating=' + rating + 'year released=' + release;` is missing `&` characters and won't be properly read by the server. Either change this to an object like in my example or add the `&` to make it a proper query string.  Secondly, you're sending certain variable names in the request but checking for *different* variable names on the server.  I.e. you send "rating" and "year released" but check for "score" and "Yreleased."

Comment: EAMann, u are the man :). thank you so much for your tips. everything is working fine right now. is there a formal way to say thanks or add points to appreciate your replies and work?  .. i will edit my code and reflect all the changes in it.. where should i go from here? what is ur advise to learn better and faster.. for this i took some snippets and rewrote what i wanted to do accordingly but i am still not strong enough to write something from scratch. thanks

Comment: The formal way would be to accept my answer as "the" answer. The best advice I have for moving forward is to keep doing what you're doing.  The more you rewrite code snippets to fit your needs, the more you'll learn about *how* to write the code.  Eventually you'll be able to write it from scratch, too.

Answer (score 0):

From the first look I can tell that the id is not passed as a parameter to the delete.php script. Try adding `data: info` to the ajax call. This might be a first step to get it working.

Another problem I see is that `$(this).attr("id")` will not give you the id of the game to delete but the id of the button element (`"Submit"`). Instead you should use `$("#ID").val()` to get the value from the hidden field.

Comment: @ryuutatsuo : thanks i am passing now 
it became now 
url: "delete.php?" + info,
data:info,

for felix , thanks i changed it, i still see the confirmation if i want to delete a record, but it is not removed from the page or the database